# escaping special characters in bash, case function

Tags: sql, database, bash

I am creating a script in bash. This script will do the same as a MySQL database kan do, I already build the functions, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and I already created a Login menu for it. Now the last thing I need to do is to be able to insert SQL statements on the command line once I run the script.I have already created the function that allows "--help" to be entered on the command line to run the Help function. I've also already created the option to enter the SELECT command on the command line, for example:

```
./database.sh SELECT name FROM student
```

This will show a complete list of names that are available in the database. But I can't get the below statement to work:

For example:

```
./database.sh SELECT * FROM student
```

This should show the complete database that is available. It doesn't though, I've alread thought of escaping the * character but that also does not work. So far I've created this below piece of code that the script will run through before it runs any functions.

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    Inlog
else
    if [ "$1" = "--help" ] ; then
        Help
    else

        case "$*" in
            "SELECT naam FROM student")
                echo "Hieronder is een overzicht van de namen van de studenten die aanwezig zijn in de database."
                echo "------------------------"
                cat $naam_dir
                ;;
            "SELECT nummer FROM student")
                echo "Hieronder is een overzicht van de studentnummers van de studenten die in de database aanwezig zijn."
                echo "------------------------"
                cat $nummer_dir
                ;;
            "SELECT mail FROM student")
                echo "Hieronder is een overzicht van de e-mail adressen van de studenten die in de database aanwezig zijn."
                echo "-----------------------"
                cat $mail_dir
                ;;
            "SELECT \*\ FROM student")
                paste $naam_dir $nummer_dir $mail_dir | expand t-20
            *)
                exit
                ;;
        esac
    fi
fi
```

I was hoping someone could help me escape these characters. A SQL query should also end with ";", so far I also have not been able to acomplish this in bash either... Maybe someone has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the `-q` switch to printf

Example

```
$ printf "%q" "'include_path=/path/to/dir'" 
\'include_path=/path/to/dir\'
```

From `help printf`:

> In addition to the standard format specifications described in printf(1)
>       and printf(3), printf interprets:

```
  %b    expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
  %q    quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
```

Comment: Hmm using the `set -f noglob` command before I run the script does not work. I don't think I have enough permissions for that, since I am building it and delivering it on a shell that is owned by school.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you will not get this to work. The reason is, that `*` as well as `;` have special meanings for the shell. I.e., `*` is a wildcard matching all files in the current directory. You would have to escape/quote it already at *command invocation*, e.g.:

```
./database.sh "SELECT * FROM student"
```

or

```
./database.sh SELECT \* FROM student
```

You don't have to escape the `*` in the case statement because it's already quoted with `"`.

The `;` sign has the special meaning that (see `man bash`) `... commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially`). That means that you always could add a `;` to the command invocation but it will not be fed to the called command as an argument, except if you escape/quote it:

```
./database.sh SELECT mail FROM student\;
```

*Edit*: I just saw Fredrik's intermediate edit.
It's possible to use `set -f` to disable file name expansion in `bash` (i.e. `*` will not be expanded). But that has to be executed in the calling shell and can not be done in the script.

Comment: Hmm alright, I already thought so myself, but my teacher said that he wants a database script, and that queries can also be done through the command line. But I don't think that this works judging on your comment.

Comment: @bryan: And why is it not possible to enclose the whole argument string in quotes, e.g. `./database.sh "SELECT * FROM student"`? In that way a query can be done through the command line...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider defining your own terms.  Rather than using * on the command line you could use ALL.  Or anything else you like.  Might even be better for the user.